# store JSON values in input fields

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

hi i'm looking for some help

I'm learning how to use Ajax and PHP and what I want to do is to run a query in PHP and store the results in a JSON.
Then I want to `echo` the JSON and set it's values into text fields.

Is this possible?

Since I'm pretty new to Ajax and jQuery I'm not sure how to do this.
I attempted to do it, but I'm only getting the first value of the array.

This is my code:

```
    <input type="text" id="text1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="send">Success Button</button>
    <input type="text" id="text2">
    <input type="text" id="text3">
    <input type="text" id="text4">


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#send").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var Rfc=$("#text1").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'search.php',
        data: 'Rfc='+Rfc,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(msg){
          var datashow = JSON.parse(msg);
          $("#text2").val(msg[0].id_person); ///this is the only value that i get
          $("#text3").val([1].person_name); ///i want to get the person's name here
          $("#text4").val([2].person_address);///i want to get the person's address here
        },
        error : function () {
          alert("error");
        }
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
<?php 

$rfc=$_POST['Rfc'];

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","transferorders");
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM person where rfc_number ='$rfc'");
$Data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $Data[]=$row;
  echo json_encode($Data);   
}

?>
```

this is what i get in console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'person_name' of undefined
    at Object.success (test ajax1.php:40)

Comment: First, I would recommend indenting your code correctly which will help with readability for you and others reviewing your code. You may also want to go through your code and make sure all tags have been closed (e.g. `</html>` is missing). There are also `<script>` tags that should be placed within the `<head>` or `<body>` sections but instead they are in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: msg[0].person_name ?

Comment: There is some basic HTML markup issues I would look first... Way before trying to mess with script loops.

Comment: **1)** The `<script>` tags have to be inside `<head>` or `<body>`. **2)** Are you loading two bootstrap versions? **3)** You should `echo`  the reulting array **after** the PHP loop has ended.

Comment: Console.log your results using `console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));` in the success callback... Just to see what result you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

bro in the PHP file try to identify every variable in the array to catch them in the script, take a look at this:

```
<?php 

$rfc=$_POST['Rfc'];

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","transferorders");
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM person where rfc_number ='$rfc'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)

    $Data = '{"id":"'.$row['id_person'].'", "name":"'.$row['person_name'].'", "address":"'.$row['person_address'].'"}';

    echo json_encode($Data);

?>
```

and the script:

```
success: function(msg){
          var datashow = JSON.parse(msg);
          $("#text2").val(datashow["id"]); ///this is the only value that i get
          $("#text3").val(datashow["name"]); ///i want to get the person's name here
          $("#text4").val(datashow["address"]);///i want to get the person's address here
        },
```

I hope it helps!